# How to read Texture Data from Graphics Memory?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

How to read Texture Data from Graphics Memory?
Once I have created glTexture, how to retrive the pixel data back?

Comment: Why do you want to? If you made the texture, surely you know what's in it. Unless you built it with glCopyTexImage or rendered to it with an FBO, you know what is in it because you put it there. Just keep the pixel data around if you need to access it later.

Answer (score 5):

**Regular OpenGL** [glGetTexImage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml)

**OpenGL ES**: You can't (you could draw the texture to a framebuffer and use glReadPixels though).

Comment: @Buttons: It's not a direct read, but takes an intermediate copy. And I just realized, that you could bind the texture as color attachment to an FBO and do a glReadPixels on that.